# Page Not Found -- Caucus badge for stackapps

Tags: discussion, 500-server-error

I was looking through the badges on the stackapps site and came accross the **Caucus** badge.   The description on the badge is as follows:

Visited an election during any phase of an active [**election**](https://stackapps.com/election) and have enough reputation to cast a vote.

If you click on the election link it takes you to a Page Not Found error and contains a picture of Sean Connery in some messed up outfit.  Anyway, does stackapps not hold elections?

[image]

Comment: Given the nature of StackApps I would have thought that elections were highly unlikely.

Comment: If that is the case then why is there a Caucus badge listed.

Comment: @todd because they may have one in the distant future

Comment: @ToddGrover - for the same reason that Stack Overflow has the [Precognitive](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/892/precognitive) badge.

Comment: The link you listed is not the same as the election link in my question.  The link the Caucus badge ahs is [http://stackapps.com/election](http://stackapps.com/election).

Comment: @ChrisF, just curious, what is that reason?  Is it just to maintain consitency across the stack sites?

Comment: **OW** that 404 page hurts my ***eyes***.... :-(

Comment: @ToddGrover - yes, plus it's a link to Area51 which trilogy users might no be aware of

Comment: Started to add an answer where you were forced to zoom into his chest until you could see the fur as a cactus with a comical badge, but I lost interest before I was done.